# How to assign client-id to a particular Kafka Producer or Topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I know that quotas are based on `client-id`. Basically I want to run the `kafka-producer-perf-test` with a particular client id to test whether the quotas work properly.

How can I assign a `client-id` for a particular producer (or) partition?

Answer (score 8):

When creating a producer, you can assign a unique value to `client.id` property

```java
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
props.put("client.id", "testclient001");
//set any additional properties.
Producer<String, GenericRecord> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, GenericRecord>(props);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your post helped in resolving issue in Kafka producer component in Pentaho

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ProducerRecord` to specify which partition you want to send message. Say partition 0. Create `KafkaConsumer` and assign consumer to specific partition (in this case partition 0). This will ensure, producer and consumer (with given client-id) both are working on same partition id of topic.

```java
ProducerRecord(java.lang.String topic, ava.lang.Integer partition, K key, V value)
```

Produce message to partition 0

```java
ProducerRecord<byte[],byte[]> record = new ProducerRecord<byte[],byte[]>("PerftestTopic", 0, key, value)
producer.send(record);
```

Consumer to read from specific partition

```java
TopicPartition partition0 = new TopicPartition("PerftestTopic", 0);
consumer.assign(Arrays.asList(partition0));
```